# Webpack - export const

Tags: webpack

I'm trying out a migration from systemjs to webpack for the first time. In my app I had something like this:

```
import {appSettings} from "AppSettings";
```

Where AppSettings was just a file with a const, not actually a module:

```
    export const appSettings = {
        somethings: {
        }
    };
```

This works with systemjs, not with webpack. Anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: Are you doing anything to make webpack support ES2015 modules?

Comment: An oversight on my part, tsconfig had a module setting of commonjs, so it wasn't finding it - nothing to do with the const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to import one of your own modules you should use a relative path:

```
import {appSettings} from "./AppSettings";
```