# TypeScript, Webpack, ES6-style modules but targeting ES5

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, systemjs

Is it possible to use TypeScript and Webpack to target ES5, but writing ES6-style modules?

I want to write modules like this:

```
export class MyClass {
}
```

And import them like this:

```
import {MyClass} from "Path/To/MyClass";
```

This works fine with SystemJS and a tsconfig like this:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
 }
```

But I'd like to use Webpack instead of SystemJS.

With "system" as the module setting I understandably get "System is not defined" as a console error.

I'm new to webpack, but perhaps there is some combination of ts-loader and babel-loader I can use? I just can't find the right configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. In version 1 of Webpack (which is the current one), system is not supported. You have to target the module to commonjs like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
 }
```

Version 2 of webpack will support system modules.

Comment: Thanks! But when I have commonjs set in tsconfig, VSCode / TypeScript language service / compiler / whatever it is gets unhappy and says it "cannot find module"

Comment: So there's probably a problem with your code. Can you post an example on how you're declaring/consuming your modules?

Comment: Your answer on my other question was the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751019/webpack-export-const